# Concatenate date variable to get epoch value in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface

I have got the date from a log file in the format YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS, in a script i am trying to get its epoch value and then print it into another log file:

```
time_extract=$(tac /home/test.log | grep -m1 "finished" | awk '{print $1 " " $2}')
epoch_last_time=$(date -d $time_extract +%s)
echo $epoch_last_time >> epoch_times.log
```

But i get nothing.

I executed the command outside the script and i got its epoch value. The date i get from log is 2021-06-02 13:38:00 and the epoch result is 1622659080.

How can i get the value by executing it in a shell?

Comment: Always quote variables unless you have a good reason not to. In this case you need to.

Comment: ```epoch_last_time=$(date -d "$time_extract" +%s)```

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the explanation,

Comment: You said it works when you run outside of a script; what does the first line of your shell script look like? What OS distribution are you using?

Comment: BTW, `...anything... | grep foo | awk '{ print ... }'` can basically always be replaced with `...anything... | awk '/foo/ { print ... }'`; no reason for grep when you have awk at hand.

Comment: @EricD I am using linux, why it does not worked inside shell script was because the time extracted from log and used to get the epoch was not enclosed by quotes

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the comment, i will implement it.